# SCSS imported font is disappearing

Tags: css, sass, postcss, eleventy

I'm working on a website based on [this template](https://github.com/philhawksworth/eleventyone) and cannot manage to import a Google Font. In my SCSS file (`styles.css`) I have

`@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap';`

and my PostCSS script looks like

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const postcss = require('postcss');

// the file name as an entry point for postcss compilation
// also used to define the output filename in our output /css folder.
const fileName = "styles.css";

module.exports = class {
  async data () {
    const rawFilepath = path.join(__dirname, `../_includes/postcss/${fileName}`);
    return {
      permalink: `css/${fileName}`,
      rawFilepath,
      rawCss: await fs.readFileSync(rawFilepath)
    };  
  };  

  async render ({ rawCss, rawFilepath }) {
    return await postcss([
      // require('postcss-comment'),
      require('precss'),
      require('postcss-import'),
      require('postcss-mixins'),
      require('postcss-color-mix'),
      require('cssnano'),
    ])  
    .process(rawCss, { from: rawFilepath })
    .then(result => result.css);
  };  
}
```

However when I build the site, the resultant `styles.css` file doesn't contain the desired import. I've tried using

- [postcss-import-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-import-url)
- [postcss-google-font](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-google-font)
- [postcss-font-magician](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-font-magician)

but had no luck with any of them. Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out after fussing with this for two days...

### What I was doing

```
@import '_variables.css';
@import '_syntax.css';
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap';
...
```

### What worked

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito&display=swap';
@import '_variables.css';
@import '_syntax.css';
...
```